# ASP.NET 4.0 application under 3.5 application pool

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

The server has .NET framework 4.0 installed but the application pool is set to 3.5.
Is there a way to force it to run my 4.0 application?
I need this because my web hosting provider takes too long to make the change for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not.

The pool can run ether on 2/3.5 version, or in 4.
Can not run on both. Now think that under any pool can live many web site. So its impossible one site to run on 4, and some other to run on 3.5.

The pool is a program that compile the webs that are under it, and then its runs them and show the pages. Many web sites can not run on different versions at the same time under the same pool, because actually there are different programs that keeps the 2/3.5 version and the 4 versions. Its different setup, different global variables, different libraries.

This two versions, 3.5 and 4.0 they live on different directories with totally different exe and dlls. So when a pool run one version of them, stay on that version.

Answer (score 1):

no, but depends on your hosting provider's control panel, you can actually set this by yourself. For example WebsitePanel you can switch between .net framework version by yourself, but again if your hosting provider assign a dedicated application pool for you, if not then it's shared with other websites which is not possible.